# How would a photon-based intelligence work in regard to relativity?

Tags: xenobiology, aliens, radiation, quantum, relativity

I want to do something interesting with Caleb Scharf’s speculation that hyper-advanced aliens could make themselves immortal by uploading themselves into the cosmic background radiation. These light creatures also quantum entangle their component photons to help with error control.
One problem is to figure out how their time perception would work. Since the aliens component particles moves as fast as light, wouldn’t some relativistic law mess with how they experience time?

Comment: Even without relativity there is the small problem that photons do not interact with photons...

Comment: I could not find any references to Scharf mentioning intelligent life in the form of radiation. I did find him time and again mentioning that things such as dark matter and dark energy might be a form taken by advanced civilizations - but those are not forms of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: There's no way to create any sort of information retaining with *ONLY* photons and nothing else. Photons and some sort of matter and you might have something. There's lots of designs for computing based on photons in some sort of device. But photons on their own, not going to happen.

Comment: Fredrik, there are too many people on this Stack who no longer believe in our guiding principle. From the [help/on-topic] we read, "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds. World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build." Please ignore every answer that says what you want to do is impossible and build your world!

Comment: If you want to write a similar story not subject to the objections others have raised, you can work with dark matter instead, or even dark energy, on whichever conjectures concerning their particulate structure you like. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_radiation) one would be especially useful.

Comment: I have never heard of Caleb Scharf or his speculations. Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: @AlexP That's not quite true. Since the EM field transports energy and momentum, it couples to itself. There are (extremely weak) gamma/gamma interactions in Feynman diagrams (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics). Think of photons as disturbing the spacetime metric ever so slightly. This can be felt by another photon.

Comment: I've not idea of the answer, but presumably, hyper-advanced aliens who can do this would have.  I'd suggest, you can either a) assume they solved this problem and can perceive time, in whatever way suits your story.  It might be best not to explain it explicitly - as long as the reader gets the idea, "someone (hyperadvanced aliens) understands it", they don't need to know.  Or, b), they can't perceive time flowing and see all times at the same time.  But they have their own time because reasons (those other rolled up dimensions from string theory?)  That's basically how we see God after all.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is pointless. There can't be photon based intelligence.

As stated [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/65053):

> As a young student, Einstein tried to imagine what an electromagnetic wave would look like from the point of view of a motorcyclist riding alongside it. But we now know, thanks to Einstein himself, that it really doesn't make sense to talk about such observers. [...]
>
> One of the most basic geometrical ideas is intersection. In relativity, we expect that even if different observers disagree about many things, they agree about intersections of world-lines. Either the particles collided or they didn't. The arrow either hit the bull's-eye or it didn't. So although general relativity is far more permissive than Newtonian mechanics about changes of coordinates, there is a restriction that they should be smooth, one-to-one functions. If there was something like a Lorentz transformation for v=c, it wouldn't be one-to-one, so it wouldn't be mathematically compatible with the structure of relativity. (An easy way to see that it can't be one-to-one is that the length contraction would reduce a finite distance to a point.)
>
> What if a system of interacting, massless particles was conscious, and could make observations? The argument given in the preceding paragraph proves that this isn't possible, but let's be more explicit. There are two possibilities. The velocity V of the system's center of mass either moves at c, or it doesn't. If V=c, then all the particles are moving along parallel lines, and therefore they aren't interacting, can't perform computations, and can't be conscious. (This is also consistent with the fact that the proper time s of a particle moving at c is constant, ds=0.) If V is less than c, then the observer's frame of reference isn't moving at c. Either way, we don't get an observer moving at c.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say the question is pointless. The answer to his last sentence is just "yes" and "relativity ruins the whole idea". It's interesting that this question was answered so directly in a physics question about relativity!

Comment: Oph, I think that's a leap. As a biologist, biology keeps throwing us curveballs. This simply eliminates the idea of an observer travelling at c. It definitely doesn't eliminate a photon based observer, and photons don't have to, and often don't, move at c. We should be careful, in science, to only claim exactly as much as our data shows.

Comment: [Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609).

Comment: @JBH "wouldn’t some relativistic law mess with how they experience time?" is the specifically requested

Comment: @L.Dutch We've gotta get back to our roots. The OP can set the rules of their universe: photonic life exists. Given that truth, how does our understanding of relativity suggest they would perceive time? In a real sense, you didn't answer the question. I wonder if it's even possible to post a frame challenge.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @elemtilas why not? OP is asking if relativistic laws would mess with the experience, and my answer is that based on those laws there can be no experience at all.

Answer (score 6):

**Insofar as we know, photons don't experience time**

And this could be an uber-cool aspect of your world. According to relativity — and from the frame reference of the photon — photons *instantly* arrive at their destination. *They experience no lifespan.*

Why? Because according to relativity, once you're traveling at the speed of light, time stops.

**But your lifeforms don't necessarily have a destination!**

Photons, for example, are emitted from a star, travel through the universe, then hit something. From the perspective of that something, that photon may have traveled for 13 billion years to finally cause skin cancer on some poor sucker who just wanted a day at the beach.

But your lifeforms *aren't doing that.* They're moving around the universe. They may have had a beginning (an "organization" of photons into a coherent and conscious being), but they don't have an end... *so long as they don't hit anything.*

**And that could be an interesting part of your world, too...**

Outer space is whomping empty,<sup>*<citation needed>*</sup> but it's not empty. There's dust and molecules and atoms floating all over out there. To us it's empty. But to your photonic lifeforms, all that stuff is hazardous to their health! Once a photon impacts with atomic matter, its energy is transferred to that matter and the photon ceases to exist.<sup>1</sup>

*That's really unhealthy for your photonic lifeforms.*

But it's really good for you, because it gives you something you can use to create a crisis-solution device in your worldbuilding or storybuilding.

**But let's get back to that stopped time issue**

The real question here is, would photonic lifeforms ever notice life such as found here on Earth? *Can they notice it?* For them all time is stopped. A photon circling a meter-diameter holding pattern over the Earth is still moving at the speed of light. Maybe it sat there doing that for fifty years... but the photon experienced *nothing.* From the moment it started circling to the moment it hit some feral oxygen atom, it experienced no time.

Which means that interacting with the rest of the universe is a bit of a problem.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *That's a simplified statement. Depending on the nature of the object the photon strikes, a number of things can happen. But for the sake of this answer, the simple statement is sufficient.*</sub>

Comment: Photons [have no inertial frame of reference of their own](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/148863/59406) so it isn't really physically meaningful to say how an individual photon "experiences" time. If you could somehow build a computational system out of multiple interacting photons (based on the subtle effects of [photon-photon scattering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488138/59406) perhaps), then presumably the speed of thought of a "photonic" computational agent would depend in some way on the time between interaction events as measured in an inertial frame.

Comment: @Hypnosifl You're trying too hard to crowbar the OP's imaginary world into the Real World. Let's use our imagination  if Taylor Swift were a group of photons, what would she experience? Unless asked otherwise, this site's purpose is to bend reality to meet the OP's creative desires. In the OP's world, photonic consciousness exists. Cool! I postulate that such an intelligence might be unable to interact with a non-photonic realms, which makes the OP's story interesting as that bridge would somehow need to be built. Whether or not photonic consciousness can exist isn't relevant (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... because that's not what the OP asked for. But I can see this question leading to another question, what would be a suspension of disbelief bridge?

Comment: If photons can't interact, I don't see how any consciousness can emerge from them. If they can, then if we assume the laws of physics aren't totally different, the time between photon A interacting with photon B and then traveling to interact with a different photon C at another location should be finite as measured in a slower-than-light inertial frame, and in any computational system the number of distinct interactions per unit time should determine the rate of subjective perception.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Modern science doesn't believe photons interact. But in the OP's world, they do. That's worldbuilding! Whether we believe or know that a consciousness can't form in Real Life is irrelevant. In fact, we do assume the laws of physics are different (from the [help/on-topic], "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build.") The rest of your comment sounds like the beginnings of a good answer!

Comment: "Modern science doesn't believe photons interact." In my earlier comment I linked to an [answer about photon-photon scattering on the physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488138/59406) specifically to show that they do interact according to modern physics (even if the interactions are subtle/rare)--that's the only basis I can see for imagining an intelligent being made of photons.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Huh, sounds like I became confused during the conversation. Thanks for straightening it out!

Answer (score 3):

### Photonic life is impossible before you even introduced general relativity to your question

Life as we know it is formed from particles bound into fixed structures created by electromagnetic forces.  You can not make life (or any sort of machine for that matter) out of anything that has no structure.  Photons which have no mass, attraction, or repulsion with one another represent one of the least structured subatomic particles you can imagine.

To try to understand this idea better.  Imagine you are given a tank full of water, and told to make a car out of it... you will find that liquid water is utterly and completely incapable of being formed into wheels, doors, framing, etc. by virtue of the fact that it lacks structure... photons have far less structure than water, and is thus that much more impossible to make life out of.

### But that does not stop you from making an organism that APPEARS to be nothing but light

While photons themselves can not be alive both for structural reasons and for time dilatation reasons as other answers have suggested, you can add some kind of [Minovsky Particles](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MinovskyPhysics) to your setting for creating an organism out of some material that meets the physical properties you want without all the annoying limitations of real world physics.  Or perhaps your could consider some variation of [Destructive Teleportation](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DestructiveTeleportation) as a sort of version of what you are asking about.

**Some possible solutions include:**

**OPTION A:** Add a new kind of Electron/Proton like set that does not interact with normal matter, but can still emit photons like normal matter.  In this case you would have intangible beings that would APPEAR to be made out of nothing but photons, because that is the only aspect of them we could interact with, but they would in fact be made out of this alternative form of matter that does not move any faster than normal matter.  In this case time dilation would be a non-issue.

**OPTION B:**  Add a new kind of subatomic particle that is massless like Photons, but has structure giving properties like the electromagnetic forces found in electrons and protons giving your beings both form and the true speed of light.  In this case you could have a being that has the physical form of a living being, but is in every other way made out of particles which can best be described as photon like.

In normal matter, electrons orbit the nucleolus at about 2200km/sec... no where near the speed of light, but still pretty impressive speeds.  That said, time dilation calculations don't really care how fast things are bobbing and weaving at a subatomic scale, they only care about how fast you move compared to other objects through space.  This means you could have a massless lepton orbiting a massless baryon at the true speed of light, but still be on average sitting still compared to its reference frame.  So in this since, you could be made out of something like photons and still experience normal time.

That said, if this massless alien where accelerated towards the speed of light compared to a reference frame, it would experience time dilation just like normal matter would.

**OPTION C:**  Light as a medium for data.  While you can not actually exist as a living being made out of photons, light is capable of being encoded with information.  So, if you want to relax you definition from "a living being" to "the instructions for creating a living being", then you might have some wiggle room with real for true photons.  If you consider the possibility that everything about a person could be encoded and shot off into space by a laser, that signal could in theory eventually be used to reconstruct that person.  They would not only not experience time while traveling as a beam of photons, they would literally not be themselves at all, only a data representation of who they are.  While this form of immortality may seem useless, it is not that unlike the idea of cryostasis.  If your aliens want to live forever, but can't because they have not solved immortality yet, the old and dying may opt to be preserved as a sort of transporter signal shot through the dead of space hoping some time in the distant future someone can show up with an FTL ship, pick up thier signal and reconstruct them... or something of that nature.

Comment: Geez, we're getting to be a hardline physics site. The question isn't even tagged with [tag:science-based] or [tag:hard-science]. [Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609). In the OP's world, there's photonic life and everything you just explained is irrelevant (see [help/on-topic]). Now what?

Comment: @JBH  I feel like a question asking about the effects of general relativity on photons is by its very nature "science-based" with or without the tag.  If the OP was not basing his question so much on real world science, I'd have certainly been less picky in my response.  
 That said, I did acknowledge that an entity like a being made out of light could possibly exist to fit the bill of what the OP is going for without running afoul of the actual scientific principles the OP has chosen to include in his story.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the OP can set the rules of their universe. I don't see how the question, "from the perspective of relativity, how would my photonic life forms perceive time?" automatically requires us to judge that they can't exist. It's irrelevant if in our universe they can't exist. However, cheers for offering options, at least that's a good frame challenge.

Comment: @JBH, He also used the Xenobiology tag. This tag says in its description that you have to be in the realm of hard science in regards to the alien lifeform.

Comment: Time to go look at the [tag:xenobiology] tag, because the human race, having not yet discovered *any* lifeform other than on the planet Earth, is completely incapable of applying hard science to extraterrestrial life. It's all just theory. (No wonder this Stack has been tilting so hard toward being another [physics.se].)

Answer (score 1):

Perception requires intelligence, intelligence requires a thought-process, and a thought-process requires a "brain" that implements it, and a brain consists of particles that exchange information between each other to come to logical conclusions and make decisions. These "particles" are neurons in a human brain, transistors in a computer or photons in the case of your photonic aliens.

You wrote that "These light creatures also quantum entangle their component photons to help with error control". Is that the medium that is used to exchange information between the photons that make up their "uploaded brain" in the cosmic background radiation? If so, remember that information can't travel instantly (not unless you invent a hypothetical physical effect that allows it). That means their though processes would be limited by how fast their quantum-entangled light particles can exchange information, which would mean that this thought-process would experience time.

Does a thought-process imply consciousness? That's a question for a philosopher to think about.